# .net core 2.0 use google login and then HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I tried it in vs Development mode, and it can work and I can login, but when I make it in my server, when I login, it says An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

```
WinHttpException: 与服务器的连接意外终止
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+d__12.MoveNext()

and my code

[image]